# Why doesn't Console.Read() return the number entered?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this is my program that i wrote in C# in visual studio 2010 Ultimate and 2008 Team System:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a=0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        a = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("you Entered : {0}",a);
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
}
```

And this is the result:

Enter a number:
5
you Entered : 53

How this possible?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you press `Q`?

Comment: You're getting the ANSI character for 5.

Comment: Char and int.... you input a char eithout conversion and the 5 just maps to ASCII char number 53. Without a converter you 5 equals 53. Output as desired.

Comment: This is a valid question for a beginner. Let's quit piling downvotes on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted to a character code. Try:

```
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 14):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) clearly states, `Read()` returns the index of the Unicode codepoint that you typed.

Comment: The documentation also gives an example of running the return value through `Convert.ToChar`.

Comment: I don't see "Unicode" anywhere in that page. So the Unicode part must come from the fact that c# does everything in Unicode.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you observed is described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reach your goal:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        ConsoleKeyInfo a = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("you Entered : {0}",a.KeyChar);
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to C#, but as far as I know, it's unnecessary to initialize your variable a when you create it. Another way to write your code could be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("you Entered : {0}", a);
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
}
```